# Find a regular expression that matches any number between 1 and 999

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to find a regular expression that matches any number between 1 and 999. I'm only allowed to use grep and it should just one expression meaning that my teacher considered this unacceptable:

```
grep -e '^[0-9]$' -e'^[0-9][0-9]$' -e '^[0-9][0-9][0-9]$' (file name.txt)
```

Would you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below grep command,

```
grep -E '^([1-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]?)$' file
```

Comment: thank you for this, it worked perfectly. not even close to anything we took in class though.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use quantifiers, which are available in extended posix regular expressions, and require the -E option to grep, instead of -e.

\b is for word boudary.

```
grep -E '\b[1-9][0-9]{,2}\b' file
```

I recommend reading 
[regular expression tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) for more information.